# Leave bash script running on remote terminal while not logged in?

Tags: bash, ssh, remote-desktop, process

I have a bash script that takes several hours to run.  While it's running, I would like to do other things, which may involve logging out or disconnecting from the internet (my script runs network tests on various computers).

I understand that there is a command that would allow me to run my tests from a remote terminal and logout of the terminal while it runs.  Does anyone know what this command is?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The command you are looking for is `nohup`.

There is also `screen`, which is for when you want to leave something running but come back and reattach interactively later.

`nohup` is simpler if a command expects no user input after launch, and `screen` is better if you want to be able to run the program interactively.

Comment: I looked at nohup right now and apparently there are issues with input and output which might cause the script to hang up.  I also saw something about screen, which strikes me as what I had read about before.  Do you know how to use either of these?

Comment: nohup is for when a script expects no user input - it saves all output to a file. Screen is for when you want to leave something running but come back and reattach interactively later. nohup is simpler if a command expects no user input after launch, and screen is better if you want to be ably to run the program interactively.

Comment: Ah found it.  For screen, it's ctrl-A d to detach and -r +pid to reattach.

Comment: Good answer.  You should add the screen comment to you answer so that it stands out more.

Answer (score 1):

I use `nohup` for this. In my case I had a python script named `action.py`
I ran the script on a remote server with `nohup python action.py &`
I would then close the terminal.
Later when it's finished running, you can see all output from the process in `nohup.out` which will be created in the same directory as `action.py`. If the file already exists further output will be appended to it.

The only snag is not knowing when the script has run its course, so in my case I had it shoot me an email upon completion. Hope this helped someone!

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you forgot to add the `nohup` Command at the beginning of your Command?

Let us say that you have run the following Long Command:

[image: The beginning of the Output of a Long Command]

This is called as `ls -Ral /` that is supposed to list all of the Files and all of the Folders, including the Hidden ones, with a Long Format, Recursively starting from the Root Folder. It might take a while.

Just press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>.

[image: Stopping the Long Command]

How do you get it back?

The Command to get it back into the Foreground is `fg`.

[image: Bringing the Command back]