# How do I run a script in the background and leave it running when I log out?

Tags: linux, bash

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Leave bash script running on remote terminal while not logged in?](https://superuser.com/questions/111631/leave-bash-script-running-on-remote-terminal-while-not-logged-in)

I have a bash script that runs Gaussian, a chemical structure calculator, which spends a couple days toying with a molecule.  It runs on a Linux box that I load the input files and said script on to, then I (am supposed to) run it, wait a while, hope the program didn't crash, and log back on to collect the result.

Somewhat of a *nx newbie, but I can't seem to figure out how to set the script running and disconnect, while letting it continue on.

```
./jobscript
```

appears to block until it's done, and if I disconnect it terminates

```
./jobscript &
```

doesn't block, I can see it running in `top`, so I thought it was OK, but on logging out it apparently killed the program.

How do I set the thing to run and stay running, even if I logout?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want to use the program `screen`. [Here is the man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/screen) for it, and [here](http://www.rackaid.com/resources/linux-screen-tutorial-and-how-to/) is a nice tutorial. It should do exactly what you want it to do - execute something in the background and be able to come back to it later.

Comment: Looks like `screen` is better for me while stumbling around in a new world; it's pretty obvious when I run a script (blocking) and it dies because of some syntax error or malformed input as it returns right away.

Answer (score 10):

You can use:

```
nohup /path/to/script >output 2>&1 &
```

Answer (score 5):

You could start a [screen](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/) session, start your job, and the disconnect from the screen session.

Later, you can reattach to your screen session to see if your job has completed.

See also https://serverfault.com/questions/2016/on-a-linux-server-how-do-you-use-multiple-terminals-over-a-single-ssh-connection/2027#2027

Comment: i highly recommend using screen over nohup

Answer (score 2):

[`nohup`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nohup)

> nohup - run a command immune to hangups, with output to a non-tty
>
> — [`man nohup`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/nohup)

Answer (score 1):

With bash:

```
my_program &
disown -h %1
```

Alter the number for your actual job number (see `jobs` builtin too)