# How to run a process and completely detach it of its parent shell

Tags: ssh, process, csh

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Leave bash script running on remote terminal while not logged in?](https://superuser.com/questions/111631/leave-bash-script-running-on-remote-terminal-while-not-logged-in)
>   [How do I detach a process from Terminal, entirely?](https://superuser.com/questions/178587/how-do-i-detach-a-process-from-terminal-entirely)

I'm running a program on a linux server that will take days to complete.

I'm launching it from my workstation from an SSH terminal, as this program is command-line only.

I want to be able to do all of these :

- launch that program,
- redirect standard outputs to files,
- exit my SSH session without making this terminate the process.

I thought about `$ ./MyProg.csh -params -foo -bar </dev/null 1>~/out.log 2>~/err.log &`

However, the process is terminated the moment I close my SSH session. My workstation is running Windows XP, and I cannot guarantee its uptime over several days, which is required for the processing of my data on the Linux server.

As you may have noted, my program requires to be launched from CSH.

Is it possible to do this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can either user `screen` or `nohup`

if you choose `screen` :

launch `screen` before you run your service:

`$ screen`

and then, run your service inside of the `screen`:

`./MyProg.sh > myprog.log` ( or anything you want here ).

and then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>d</kbd>

when you came back, just:

`$ screen -r`

for more information: http://www.gnu.org/s/screen/

---

about the nohup :
just:

`nohup ./MyProg.sh > myprog.log &`

Comment: AWESOME! I knew I could manage using `screen` but I wasn't able to get through it. This is plain awesome, thank you so much!

Comment: I think the "disown" command will do what he OP asked for....

Answer (score 1):

Make a shell wrapper like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
exec </dev/null
exec >> ~/out.log
exec 2>> ~/err.log
exec setsid ./MyProg.csh -params -foo -bar
```

If you need PID file too, then send this shell script to bg and read $! (PID of last bg process). You can do it using subshell with () in the same script like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
( exec </dev/null
  exec >> ~/out.log
  exec 2>> ~/err.log
  exec setsid ./MyProg.csh -params -foo -bar
) &
kill -0 $! > /dev/null 2>&1 || exit 1
echo $! > program.pid
exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

The connection drops because the shell sends SIGHUP to all children when it exits.
If you use bash or zsh, you can use `disown` and the shell will no longer send SIGHUP and the processes will stay around.

`screen` and `setsid` above works, but this answer has the advantage of not having to remember to do screen before you start anything.  `screen` has a lot of power other than this, so you may want to get into a habit of using it.

Comment: I *have* to use csh.